# Estimation non-linear function with restrictions and bounds in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I want to estimate yield curve using Nelson-Siegel model. This is parametric non-linear model with 4 parameters : beta0, beta1, beta2 and delta

[image]

I have two data-frames : the first includes price per bond, and the second includes cashflow : payment and time-to-maturity per bond.

I am trying to solve next non-linear optimization problem :

[image]

where Price is price of bond and Predicted Price is that has been calculated using Nelson Siegek parameters.

[image]

where y(m) is yield calculated by Nelson-Siegel model.

Moreover, for some of parameters i have bounds and restrictions.

Now is my question, how can i estimate Nelson-Siegel model and which method i should use?

I read in the forum that for non-linear models with bounds /restrictions, i should use scipy.minimize "SLSQP" method.

Comment: Yes, you can use the [`scipy.optimize.minimize()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function for most optimization problems. Common internet search engines should turn up plenty of examples and tutorials. It would not make much sense to write another one as an answer here.

Comment: Thank you very much